# get_terms - get total number of results when 'include' array is given

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to get 12 term objects by calling `get_terms`; and I have a specific array of `terms_ids` which should come first.

Here is my query so far:

```
$term_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
    'number' => 12,
    'include' => $location_terms,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpc_is_featured',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);

$store_terms = get_terms( $term_args );
```

The problem is that since `$location_terms` consists of only 3 values, the whole result count is also restricted to 3. I know this is not quite possible as per [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) documentation.

Is there any hack to get the rest 9 results, after getting the 3 from that array?

**UPDATE**

I have achieved it by using 2 queries as described in @Yoda's answer. Is there any way to get it done by using `get_terms` only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... this basically doesn't work.

The `include` parameter sets up a where condition in the SQL query that requires all results to be within the `include` array.

So, that's not great for what you're after.

However, I do have a solution for you!

```
$term_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
    'number' => 12,
    'include' => $location_terms,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpc_is_featured',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);

$store_terms_location = get_terms( $term_args );

$term_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
    'number' => 12 - count($store_terms_location), // only get as many as you still need
    'exclude' => $location_terms,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpc_is_featured',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);

$store_terms_other = get_terms( $term_args );

// merge the two arrays together in order of priority
$store_terms = array_merge($store_terms_location, $store_terms_other);
```

So, to cover what this does:

- Get up to 12 location terms
- Get the remaining number of terms from a list that excludes the ones we checked for earlier
- Merge the two lists together

This should give you the results you need. You can tidy it up, use some conditionals to determine whether the latter part needs to run, etc. Build on the general idea and make it fit what you're trying to do with your code.

Comment: This is perfect, and i am now following this method only, i was wondering if we can do it in a single query. so that i can reduce some mili seconds avoiding the 2nd query.

Comment: You could, but you'd need to basically write your own version of WP_Terms::query. Pretty sure there's no way to do it as part of the existing query.

What you could do is look at caching it, so it only needs to look it up once and then it remembers. But how feasible that is depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let it be in the way as it is. For now 2 queries as per your answer will do fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

If you **already know** the identity of the three terms you to have get first in your array, making a query to get those is kinda irrelevant. You could simply make two separate queries and merge the results.

E.g.:

```
$first_terms = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
    'include' => $location_terms,
);

$store_terms_1 = get_terms( $term_args );


$remaining_terms = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
    'number' => 9,
    'exclude' => $location_terms,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wpc_is_featured',
            'value'   => 'on',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);

$store_terms_2 = get_terms( $term_args );

$resulting_terms = array_merge( $store_terms_1, $store_terms_2 );
```

Without knowing more about your data, it is not easy to do much more.

Guesstimating a bit, since you are already using term metas in your query, you could add another term meta with the order, and use **that** to order your results. This way you wouldn't need to hardcode those first three terms that you want to have on top, **and you would only need to make one query**.

E.g.:

```
 $store_terms = [
        'taxonomy' => 'coupon_store',
        'number' => 12,
        'meta_key' => 'coupon_store_term_order,
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key'     => '_wpc_is_featured',
                'value'   => 'on',
                'compare' => '=',
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

This way, you have to set up a new term meta for your terms (`coupon_store_term_order`), and save there your desired order. You would need a bit more fiddling (e.g. deal with terms with no defined order, etc).

And logically, I'm further assuming that these three terms are also featured terms. Otherwise, making two requests and merging is still the only logical way to go.

Comment: $location_terms may include IDs that are not featured, and thus there is a variable factor involved just from the example. Just because it's getting three results now does not mean it always will, and that should be reflected in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that's neither here nor there. It's up to the OP, and beyond the requirements they set up. Can't guess all their requirements and data.

Comment: Neither can I, but it's within their example and you've tossed it aside without considering whether it's important to their requirements.

Comment: I don't know why this is so important to you. But I didn't _toss it aside_, I focused in the important bits of the question; I'm not supposed to deliver a full working solution, but present an answer that's helpful for future visitors. Beyond that, I actually read the OPs question and think my code is better: since you are already using `include`, the meta query is irrelevant. The OP said they wanted those three items, not _those three items if they are featured_. Still, you are welcome to your opinion. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: The phrase was that because $location_terms only has three IDs in it, only three things are returned - not that the OP only wanted three items. Reading the code contextually, there is potentially more going on than we can see, and lopping off the meta query because you don't think it is relevant to that part of the question isn't helpful. The OP wouldn't include it if they didn't want to use it.

Comment: @yivi 1st of all the edit you have made to my question is totally useless, i guess its only for badge, to edit and answer same question within 12 hours, 2nd thing, $fisrt_terms is not applicable to me as meta_query is not used. What I need is to get is done using get_terms once or by a single query. Help me is there is a way around for that.

Comment: @Undefined, couldn't care less about badges. Just trying to help. I'm sorry you disliked my edit. It fixed a couple of orthographical errors and attempted to clarify things. Still, my answer is exactly the same than the one you found useful. Plus the second part addresses how to do it using only one query, if you want to use it. Happy coding.